# How can I get started developing with Django on Cloud9?

Tags: django, cloud9-ide

So Cloud9 looks really cool, and you can create python files in it, but I can't figure out how to get it to run a Django project. I imported one from my github account into the IDE, but it says I need to install Django (a django.core import error) so I need to help getting going.  Any Ideas? Any skeleton projects on the web that I missed that will do this?

Comment: try "easy_install django" command first

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After some research and looking for an answer on different blogs and sites I finally found a solution:

- Create a new workspace
- Execute `easy_install django` to install Django
- Create new Django project `python ./../bin/django-admin.py startproject myproject`
- Start dev server `python ./myproject/manage.py runserver $IP:$PORT`
- Access http://projectname.username.c9.io
- **Voilà!!!**

I hope this helps

Comment: Dont know if they changed it but `$IP` worked for me (instead of `$OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP`). Just a heads up.

Comment: I had to use $PORT to make it run

Answer (score 0):

Just write commands in shell as it is:
`sudo pip install -r requirements.txt` (you should have there django)
than
`python manage.py runserver $IP:$PORT`
you will have app on https://projectname-username.c9.io

Answer (score 0):

You may also have to add the proper path: `<workspace_name>-<username>.c9users.io` to the ALLOWED_HOSTS list in django_project/settings.py file, as suggested by the error message returned by django server. Tested on Django 2.0